# tmpfs /run full

Tags: systemd-journald, tmpfs

I have a problem with /run partition, its size NEVER decrease so when it's full, I have to reboot.

```
[root@centos]# df -H
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
tmpfs           6.4G  6.3G   34M 100% /run
...
```

[image]

What is expected is 408M in Used not 6.3G

```
[root@centos]# du -h /run/log/journal/
408M    /run/log/journal/d5b1a7595c414aef867926a90584852b
408M    /run/log/journal/
```

[image]

The size of /run/log/journal is stable but doesn't decrease the size of /run partition (tmpfs)

```
[root@centos]journalctl --disk-usage
Archived and active journals take up 408.0M on disk.
```

what I try:
In /etc/systemd/journald.conf, I set these parameters:

> RuntimeMaxUse=400M
>   RuntimeKeepFree=2G

```
systemctl kill --signal=SIGUSR2 systemd-journald.service
journalctl --vacuum-size=400M
journalctl --vacuum-time=1d


journalctl --verify

lsof -nP +L1 /run
```

> COMMAND     PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NLINK      NODE
>   NAME
>
> systemd       1     root   25u  FIFO   0,19      0t0     1      9824
>   /run/systemd/initctl/fifo
>
> rsyslogd    542     root  mem    REG   0,19 16777216     1 393167600
>   /run/log/journal/d5b1a7595c414aef867926a90584852b/sys
>
> rsyslogd    542     root  mem    REG   0,19  8388608     1 393003455
>   /run/log/journal/d5b1a7595c414aef867926a90584852b/sys0a164e4eada90b8dbc31bb75-0000000000d861da-0005650fb1201005.journal
>   ...

I have to reboot the server every time /run is full.
How to resolve this problem?

Thanks for your help.

OS informations:
centos 7.2
linux 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 29 17:29:29 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
journalctl --version
```

> systemd 219
>   +PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN

[EDIT]: RuntimeMaxUse and RuntimeKeepFree doesn't help
[image]

Comment: The most common reason for this is a file descriptor which is still being written to on this partition but has been erased from the directory.  Stopping the process that writes to it (which may be tedious to find) solves the issue, which is why rebooting does.

Comment: This is often caused by people who try to delete files in order to save space without considering the application that writes to them.

Comment: How many files do you have in /run/log?

Comment: Is this a server upgraded from a previous version?

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro: 52 files, 3 yesterday and 49 today, it's not a server upgraded from a previous version

Comment: @Julie Pelletier: lsof command line shows that these files are used by rsyslogd. So what can I do?

Comment: This is unusual.  You should check your `rsyslogd` configuration.